# Css / Container with flexbox layout on mobile devices

Tags: css, styled-components

Problem making a responsive container with flex layout
basically i'm looking for this:

[image]

but i got this on mobile devices:

[image]

I'm not able to make responsive on mobile devices everything is strange
and I think my code was huge for something that is small
code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        background: "none",
        height: "100%",
        margin: "0 auto",
        maxWidth: "80rem",
        paddingRight: "10px",
        paddingLeft: "10px"
      }}
    >
      <NewsFlex>
        <div className="on_action_left">
          <div className="title">
            <p className="text-title">act</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content-header">
            <h3 className="content-text" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
              aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            </h3>
            <p className="date-text" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
              <span>icon</span>
              11 de Fevereiro de 2020
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="on_action_right">
          <div id="on_action_cards top">
            <div className="title">
              <p className="text-title">act</p>
            </div>
            <div className="content-header">
              <h3 className="content-text" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
              </h3>
              <p className="date-text" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                <span>icon</span>
                11 de Fevereiro de 2020
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="on_action_cards bottom">
            <div className="bottom_left_card">
              <div className="title">
                <p className="text-title">act</p>
              </div>
              <div className="content-header">
                <h3 className="content-text" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                  Ebbbbbbbb
                </h3>
                <p className="date-text" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                  <span>icon</span>
                  11 de Fevereiro de 2020
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="bottom_right_card">
              <div className="title">
                <p className="text-title">act</p>
              </div>
              <div className="content-header">
                <h3 className="content-text" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                  dasssss
                </h3>
                <p className="date-text" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                  <span>icon</span>
                  11 de Fevereiro de 2020
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </NewsFlex>
    </div>
```

css:

```
const HeaderKeyFrame = keyframes`
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
`;
const FlexColumn = css`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;
const FlexRowCenter = css`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;
const NewsFlex = styled.div`
  ${FlexRowCenter}
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  & .on_action_left {
    ${FlexColumn}
    cursor:pointer;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 40px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 500px;
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 200px -200px 5px 400px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 200px -200px 5px 400px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    box-shadow: inset 200px -200px 5px 400px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 2px;
  }

  & .on_action_right {
    ${FlexColumn}
    width: calc(100% - 500px);
    height: 70vh;

    & > div:nth-child(1) {
      ${FlexColumn}
      cursor:pointer;
      align-items: flex-start;
      padding: 20px 20px;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
      box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
      background: green;
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    & > div:nth-child(2) {
      ${FlexRowCenter}
      justify-content:space-between;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    & .bottom_left_card {
      ${FlexColumn}
      cursor:pointer;
      align-items: flex-start;
      padding: 20px 20px;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: blue;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
      box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
      margin-right: 1px;
    }
    & .bottom_right_card {
      ${FlexColumn}
      cursor:pointer;
      align-items: flex-start;
      padding: 20px 20px;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: red;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
      box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 5px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
      margin-left: 1px;
    }
  }
  & .text-title {
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    line-height: 13px;
    pointer-events: auto;
    background-position: top center;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #009ffd, #2a2a72);
    animation: ${HeaderKeyFrame} 5s ease infinite;
    background-size: 150% 100%;
    color: #fff;
  }
  & .content-text {
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.07692308rem !important;
    font-family: Roboto Slab, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  & .date-text {
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 0.6692308rem !important;
    font-family: sans-serif, serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    & > span {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
  }
`;
```

example on code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-sky-3zmrq

Answer (score 0):

because your code is not poor CSS I can't change it, I can only say these tips to you.
first of all, you have to use the mobile-first approach.
gird module is most helpful for this design vs flex module.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

What you want to be doing is:

- Creating a default css grid layout
- using FlexBox to polyfill that grid on older browsers
- use media queries to change the layout and make it more friendly

I precisely you wrote an article about it [here](https://dioxmio.medium.com/grid-vs-flexbox-which-one-should-you-be-using-471cb955d3b5) which I look into FlexBox and Grid and their most common usages. you'll probably find it useful